# How do I specify the Emacs start up screen on a Windows7 computer with multiple screens?

Tags: emacs

I am running GNU Emacs 24.2.1 on a Windows7 computer with three screens.  How can I tell emacs the screen I'd like it to start in?  Dragging my Emacs window across screens is exhausting.  ;)

Comment: maybe better superuser?  As it isn't directly related to programming, perhaps asking as general how to I make a program start on a specific screen? (sorry can't help you, no windows here)

Comment: @Doon - I asked here, because Emacs tends to have many obscure, special-purpose variables and functions, and it also has some special coommand-line arguments.  However, I have to admit, I'm not too familiar with SuperUser, and which questions are better posed there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

on windows xp just now I tried using the `-geometry` [command-line option](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/emacs19/emacs_37.html#SEC385). I found that increasing the x-offset was sufficient to determine which monitor emacs appeared on. As explained [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FrameSize), you can simply edit the properties of your windows shortcut to add the extra argument.

1st monitor

```
C:\emacs-24.2\bin\runemacs.exe -geometry +100
```

2nd monitor

```
C:\emacs-24.2\bin\runemacs.exe -geometry +1400
```

This worked on xp for me; hopefully will work on win7 for you.

Comment: +1  I'm hoping for an answer that lets me explicitly specify a screen.  However, I consider this to be a clever hack, and I hadn't thought of specifying a large x-offset to force the emacs window over to the next screen.  Cheers!